# How to inhibit only auto suspend when running certain apps?

Tags: suspend

I find this weird in Linux:

With auto-suspend enabled, the unattended computer goes to sleep even though a music player (or any other process) is running.

This is annoying when I want to leave computer on and listen to some music or when I want to use it as HTPC.

System: INTEL Core i3-2100, Asus P8H67-M EVO INTEL H67 and a SSD. (And I don't have a swap partition.)

Should I do something in BIOS or are there other solutions including an app? (Caffeine inhibits screensaver as well and I don't want that.) A DE agnostic solution would be preferable (I'm on LXDE).